# adding a gravatar issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an issue where I am trying to add a gravatar image to my code from the learn by examples book chapter 7
the site shows  up fine but I am unable to pass the rspec spec test, I get the following errors:

> 1) UsersController should have the right title
>        Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user
>        ActionController::RoutingError:
>          No route matches {:id=>nil, :controller=>"users", :action=>"show"}
>        # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in '
>
> 2) UsersController should include the user's name
>        Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user
>        ActionController::RoutingError:
>          No route matches {:id=>nil, :controller=>"users", :action=>"show"}
>        # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in '
>
> 3) UsersController should have a profile image
>        Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user
>        ActionController::RoutingError:
>          No route matches {:id=>nil, :controller=>"users", :action=>"show"}
>        # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in '
>
> 4) UsersController GET 'show' should be successful
>        Failure/Error: get :show, :id =>  @user
>        ActionView::Template::Error:
>          undefined method `gravatar_image_tag' for #<#<Class:0x00000003dda0d8>:0x00000003dd31c0>
>        # ./app/helpers/users_helper.rb:4:in`gravatar_for'
>        # ./app/views/users/show.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___2751740854697998587_32401380__1353884467646085556'
>        # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:13:in`block (3 levels) in '
>
> 5) UsersController GET 'show' should find the right user
>        Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user
>        ActionView::Template::Error:
>          undefined method `gravatar_image_tag' for #<#<Class:0x00000003dda0d8>:0x00000002c7e140>
>        # ./app/helpers/users_helper.rb:4:in`gravatar_for'
>        # ./app/views/users/show.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___2751740854697998587_32401380__1353884467646085556'
>        # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:18:in`block (3 levels) in '

To give you a little background I accidentally added the gravatar gem to the wrong area but I did change it back to the correct area

spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb

```
it "should have the right title" do
get :show, :id => @user
response.should have_selector("title", :content => @user.name)
end

it "should include the user's name" do
get :show, :id => @user
response.should have_selectori("h1", :content => @user.name)
end

it "should have a profile image" do
get :show, :id => @user
response.should have_selector("h1>img", :class => "gravatar")
end
end
```

app/controllers/Users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@title = @user.name
end
```

app/helpers/users_helper.rb

```
module UsersHelper

def gravatar_for(user, options = { :size => 50 })
gravatar_image_tag(user.email.downcase, :alt => user.name,
                :class => 'gravatar',
                :gravatar => options)
end
end
```

app/views/users/show.html.erb

```
<%= @user.name %>, <%=  @user.email %>

<table class="profile" summary="Profile Information">
<tr>
<td class="main">
<h1>
<%= gravatar_for @user %>
<%= @user.name %>
</h1>
</td>
<td class="sidebar round">
<strong>Name</strong> <%= @user.name %><br />
<strong>URL</strong> <%= link_to user_path(@user), @user %>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

For somebody who has the same error:  make sure that in file users_controller_spec.rb lines:

```
      before(:each) do
        @user = Factory(:user)
      end
```

is placed right after **render_views** otherwise user is not created for each method.

Answer (score 0):

:id=>nil, maybe user is not logged in? and you need check it by using <% if current_user %>

Comment: I do not think that is the case

Comment: $ rails console
>> user = User.first
>> user.update_attributes(:email => "example@railstutorial.org",
?>
:password => "foobar",
?>
:password_confirmation => "foobar")
=> true

Comment: also how do I check it using that code, sorry I am a real beginner at this

Answer (score 0):

Your errors are clearly showing that `:id => nil` which is not what is expected to be the case for the `:action => :show` route.

This often happens in specs when you have not properly set up the `@user`...
I bet if you changed one of your specs to this:

```
it "should have the right title" do
  @user.id.should_not be_blank
  get :show, :id => @user
  response.should have_selector("title", :content => @user.name)
end
```

That it would fail on the very first line - saying something like "nil expected to not be blank".

The way to solve it would be to ensure that `@user` is getting properly initialised with a user.

As @user861181 pointed out, this can be done in a `before(:each)` block by setting up a factory. Alternatively (if you use fixtures), you can use:

```
  before(:each) do
    @user = users(:one)
  end
```